# Is it possible to allow Qt::QueuedConnection only on Qt signals?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have a C++ class `EventHandler` which provides some API with Qt signals. I want to guarantee that the execution time of the code which emits those signals will  not be affected by execution time of the connected slots. I.e. if connected slots executes too long it shouldn't slow down the emitting code.

First idea that came to me is to enforce all users of `EventHandler` class using `Qt::QueuedConnection` when connecting a slot. But is it possible to do it technically? Maybe some flag like `Q_QUEUED_ONLY` near signal declaration, which would cause `QObject::connect()` with connection type other than `Qt::QueuedConnection` to fail? I can't find anything appropriate in docs.

Comment: You should consider the effect a forced type of connection can have if the user of your class decides to move its instance to a different thread. Speaking of threads you can move the even handling part to a different thread using a worker thread. `QRunnable` is also a nice option here.